# c# convert double to string and check length in one expression

Tags: c#, tostring

Is there any way to replace the second and third line with one expression?

```
double oddOrEven = 1231713.0;

string myString = oddOrEven.ToString();

if (myString[myString.Length - 3] == '7')
    Console.WriteLine("The third digit is a 7");
```

Instead of creating a new string variable and using that to make the check in the IF, I wanted to just do something like this:

```
double oddOrEven = 1231713.0;

if (oddOrEven[oddOrEven.Length - 3].ToString() == '7')
    Console.WriteLine("The third digit is a 7");
```

I realize that wont work, but is there any way to arrange it so I can get the same effect that I want without having to create and use a new variable?
Maybe I should not be using ToString?
Thank you!

Comment: I still wonder what should happen if the double has significant decimals...

Comment: @Vland  Not sure what this means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use strings you can do it this way:

```
if (Math.Truncate((oddOrEven / 100)) % 10 == 7)
Console.WriteLine("The third digit is a 7");
```

Comment: Thank you this is the best way to approach what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
if (oddOrEven.ToString()[oddOrEven.ToString().Length - 3] == '7')
    Console.WriteLine("The third digit is a 7");
```

However it may not be more efficient, since ToString() is called twice.
Also, the code becomes less easy to read, but as long as it works, and you know the consequences, it's up to you :)

Comment: Oh very good to know that that works... not the best method as you say however. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Linq version

```
   if (oddOrEven.ToString().Reverse().ToArray()[2] == '7')
            Console.WriteLine("The third digit is a 7");
```